# Concerning persistence size in the Linux Live Creator

Tags: linux, usb, persistence

Message : Hello everyone!
I have ,for the last several months, used the Linux Live USB Creator which it is a very useful app to make portable OS on to flash drives. I mostly use this application to test and try out new OS's as they are released, before I decide to make a hard disk installatio on to the computer.

In many cases, the application developers will allow the “persistence” feature in the flash-drive-installed OS, which is just another way of saying that after multiple boot-ups and shutdowns, all the changes made to the OS will be saved in the flash-drive. 
But I have a question about the limit of the Persistence size in Linux Live USB Creator (currently version 2.6).

I install Super OS 10 on to a partition on my external drive which has 30 GB. I wanted to reserve 10 GB for the persistence so that I can install more applications and space will not run out as I update the installed applications or when I do system updates. But why is it that only 3950 MB can be put for persistence? 
It would be great if, when desired, as much more persistence space could be set aside so that the space will not run out soon.

Also, as I have installed the OS on a 30 GB drive, I tried to see how much space is left. But it seems only the remaining of the Persistence space is displayed when I click on the File System folder. For example, after I have just installed it now, there is 3.5 GB of free space. Where can I access the remaining 26 GB or so drive space which is in the same drive? How do I access it Sir??

It would be helpful if any one  could explain and help me with this.
Most importantly,  it would be a big relief if the persistence can be somehow expanded by a work-around so that I can continue using my SuperOS 10.04 (now heavily customized) OS, which unfortunately has just over 576 MB of space left now, after I removed OpenOffice.org and installed the Libre Office earlier today. This is what remains from the maximum allowable 3950 MB of space for persistence at set-up.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you realy should create a persistent **partition** on your USB flash drive. This way you'll get rid of the Fat 4 GB file size limit.

Here a nice [pendrivelinux tutorial](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/create-a-larger-than-4gb-casper-partition/) showing how to do that using Gparted. Just make sure to label the partition accordingly to the live distro you use: `casper-rw` for *Buntu, `persistent` for others like Debian.

Answer (score -1):

VFAT only supports files up to 4GB in size. Try using another filesystem.